# MySQL - COALESCE using result to join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get JOIN a table after I get a result from a SELECT with COALESCE

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(
            (
                SELECT
                      relocations.location_id
                FROM
                      relocations
                WHERE
                      parts.id=relocation.part_id
                ORDER BY
                      relocations.date_moved
                DESC
                LIMIT 
                      1
            )
            ,
            parts.location_id
       ) AS locationId,
    locations.name
FROM
    parts
JOIN
    locations ON locations.id=locationId
```

However the query is not valid and MySQL tells me locationId is an Unknown column. How could I fix this?

**Table structure**

[Parts]
id | location_id

[Relocations]
id | location_id | date_moved

[Locations]
id | name

Comment: Table structure?  Intended purpose of query?

Comment: Please post a schema. I can't tell which `locationid` you're referring to.

Comment: @eggyal see updated post. purpose is to grab the latest location for the part if it has been relocated (this may seem weird but i had to strip down my original query to make it easier to work with).

Comment: @njk I am joining locations.id=locationId where locationId is from the COALESCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to join on the `COALESCE` column. Try this:

```
SELECT a.locationId, locations.name FROM
    (SELECT
        COALESCE(
                    (
                    SELECT
                          relocations.location_id
                    FROM
                          relocations
                    WHERE
                          parts.id=relocation.part_id
                    ORDER BY
                          relocations.date_moved
                    DESC
                    LIMIT 
                          1
                )
                ,
                parts.location_id
           ) AS locationId
    FROM
        parts) a
JOIN locations ON locations.id=a.locationId
```

Comment: I've tweaked your query a bit to remove a blatant "MySQL won't accept this" error, but seeing as `a.locationId` is the same as `locations.id`, you might actually want to restructure the whole thing as `SELECT id, name FROM locations WHERE id IN (SELECT ...)`. I think that'll be a lot simpler.

Comment: It's going to take me a sec to try and work this into the huge query (since this was just a section of it).